# Azure Cli how to change subscription default

Tags: azure, azure-cli2

I have 3 subscription in my Azure Account, I need to change the default subscription. When i Run the command:

```
azure account list
```

I have this output:

[image]

I have tried to change the default or current subscription on this way, with no results...

```
azure config set subscription {{MyIdSubscription}}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: An important tip!
Be careful mixing Azure Shell and Powershell - eg. "az login" and "Connect-AzAccount"
If you use "az login" it will not reflect on commands like Get-AzContext.
So if you have powershell scripts that depend on Get-AzContext they'll fail.

Answer (score 348, accepted):

For Azure CLI 2.0 (preview) I had to use

```
az account set --subscription <name or id>
```

Comment: If you have just recently updated from 'Free Trial` to Pay-As-You-Go you may need to `az logout && az login` again to see the current subscriptions. Otherwise it won't know about your changed subscriptions.

Comment: Let me add only that if you want to set the default subscription in a bash script using a variable like AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION="MyAzureSubscription", you've to use the command az account set --subscription "${AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION}" to avoid some bash errors...you cannot evaulate it directly as az account set --subscription $AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION

Comment: If you want to know the subscription id use the command `az account list` and from the output use the `id` entry.

Answer (score 33):

Please try the following:

```
azure account set -s {Subscription Id}
```

That should change the subscription.

Comment: Will it be also changing the subscription on the UI , in case a person is a part of multiple subscription ?

Comment: I had to use `az` instead of `azure`

Answer (score 30):

```
1. List all the subscriptions you have

    az account list --output table
    
      Name             CloudName     SubscriptionId     State     IsDefault
    ---------------   ------------  ----------------  ---------  ----------
    AssociateProd      AzureCloud    xxxxxxxxxxxx       Enabled    False

2. Pick the subscription you want and use it in the command below.

    az account set --subscription <subscription_id>
```

Answer (score 12):

Azure CLI latest (2.39.0):

```
az account set (--name or -n) <name>

az account set (--subscription or -s) <id>
```

Answer (score 10):

Use **id** (subscription id) that is GUID, which will be listed when you did  `az login`

[image]

And then execute the below command..

```
az account set --subscription fffde5cb-cccc-aaaa-eee-457c3292608e
```

Comment: `az login` is mandatory, before the `az account set -s` command even works! Thx :)

Answer (score 9):

Try in this way.it worked for me to set Azure PowerShell to a specific Azure Subscription

```
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "t666-e251-49ce-a1cd-5c3144"
```

Comment: Note: `Set-AzContext` is Azure Powershell cmdlet, not Az CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a wrapper around the Azure-CLI for this in a PiP Package, with colors.

pip install [azure-account-switcher](https://github.com/abij/az-account-switcher)

> note: it's dependent on azure-cli which downloads a lot of dependencies. So you should install in environment with azure-cli already present.

[image: Example-usage]

Answer (score 0):

An important tip for those that have used `az account list` but cannot find requried subscription among the listed ones, and the `az account set` does not accept the id returning

> The subscription of 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx' doesn't exist
> in cloud 'AzureCloud'.

If that's the case, all you need to do is relogin to clear the cache:

`az login`, complete the procedure and the account list should be now updated (logout shoud not be needed)