# switching subscription id within a management group setup in azure - getting the error The subscription of xxx doesn't exist in cloud '

Tags: azure

I have recently moved onto a management group structure in azure under a single root subscription. I would like to deploy resources but i am unable to target a specific subscription.

Checked the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475104/azure-cli-how-to-change-subscription-default)

Doesnt seem to work.

`az account set --subscription sandbox-subscription`

A screenshot of my setup can be seen below.

At the moment, the default subscription is `Pay-As-You-Go`, I would like to be able to change that programmatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces a similar issue, the solution is to re-authentication onto azure cli by running.

`az login`

not sure what happened before, but after re-authenticating it now works and I can see all subscriptions.